# Python Pandas Data Frame Inserting Many Arbitrary Values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
       A
0   Apple
1  orange
2    pear
3   apple
```

For index values 4-1000, I want all of them to say "watermelon".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reindex and fill NaNs:

```
df.reindex(np.r_[:1000]).fillna('watermelon')
```

Or,

```
df = df.reindex(np.r_[:1000])
df.iloc[df['A'].last_valid_index() + 1:, 0] = 'watermelon'  # df.iloc[4:, 0] = "..."
```

```
              A
0         Apple
1        orange
2          pear
3         apple
4    watermelon
5    watermelon
...
999  watermelon
```